# save graph with python igrapg: ""killed"" program by the RAM

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to save my graph file by picklez in python using the igraph package.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
from igraph import Graph
G = Graph.Full(34000)# undirected so about 578 millions edges
print('G is done..!')    
G.write_picklez('/home/.../test_full.picklez')
```

I get the following message(after building the network and during G.write_picklez):

```
print('G is done..!') 
killed
```

my system resources:64G ram, 8-cores CPU, and 30G free storage, and they are free.

I used other formats also, but I get the 'Killed' error message. Some sources say this library(igraph) can handle millions of nodes and billions of links. How?  can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that the path should start with `/home`? I don't think mac and windows have such a folder

Comment: Mac does have a folder called `/home` but you need special access, can you try a different file to test if that works?

Comment: @ Louisb Boucquet: I work on ubuntu 20

Comment: Dear @LouisbBoucquet: I deleted the unused file in the /tmp directory, but I get the "killed" message. I have 64 gig ram and 4gig swap area supportive for ram. I really do not know what to do?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? It seem you use `/home/...`, which should probably be 2 dots, not 3. Why not simply test using `/home/test.picklez`, while making sure you actually have write permissions in that directory?

Comment: Dear @LouisbBoucquet I used 3 dots because I didn't want to write details. I tested the code and path with a smaller network (<34000) and everything was ok. I have sudo permission on this system and don't have a permission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`igraph` developer here.

`killed` tends to happen when you run out of RAM. `igraph` can handle large graphs, in particular support for 64 bit integers has improved on the `develop` branch which will soon be released as `0.10`.

I recommend you try with a smaller graph first, then increase the graph size gradually while monitoring your RAM usage and see if you're running out of memory.

Comment: Dear @iosonofabio thanks for your reply and recommendation. This answer was helpful because I realized there was nothing wrong with my code.